# Barycenter maps that are "submultiplicative" with respect to group actions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

**Background and notation**

For a set $X$,  we denote $\mathcal{P} (X)$ to be the finitely supported measures on $X$, i.e.,  $\nu \in \mathcal{P} (X)$ is of the form
$$\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_{x_i},$$
where $a_1, ..., a_n \in [0,1],  \sum a_i =1$ and $x_1,..., x_n \in X$.  Given a group $\Gamma$ acting on $X$, $\mu \in \mathcal{P} (\Gamma)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal{P} (X)$,  we define $\mu * \nu \in \mathcal{P} (X)$ in the usual way,  i.e.,  if $\nu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_{x_i}$ and $\mu = \sum_{j=1}^{k} b_j \delta_{g_j}$,  then
$$\mu * \nu = \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^n b_j a_i \delta_{g_j x_i}.$$

Following [Mendel and Naor, Section 1.2](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enaor/homepage%20files/cat0-extension.pdf), we define a barycentric map to be a map  $\rm bar : \mathcal{P} (X) \rightarrow X$ such that $\rm bar  (\delta_x) = x,  \forall x \in X$.   For a metric space $(X,d)$ and a constant $p \in [1,  \infty)$,  a barycentric map $\rm bar : \mathcal{P} (X) \rightarrow X$ is called a $W_p$ barycentric map,  if there is a constant $C \geq 1$ such that for every $\nu_1, \nu_2 \in \mathcal{P} (X)$ it holds that
$$d (\rm bar (\nu_1),  \rm bar (\nu_2)) \leq C W_p (\nu_1,  \nu_2),$$
where $W_p$ is the Wasserstein $p$ metric, i.e.,
$$W_p (\nu_1,  \nu_2) = \inf_{\nu \in ( \nu_1 \vert \nu_2)} \left( \int_{X \times X} d (x,y)^p d \nu (x,y) \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Perhaps the simplest example of this situation is when $X$ is a normed space.  In that case,  there is a natural barycentric map
$$\rm bar ( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_{x_i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i,$$
and it is not hard to show that this is a $W_1$ barycentric map.

It was also shown that non-positive curvature implies the existence of $W_p$ barycentric maps.  Namely,  in [Sturm, Theorem 6.3](https://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Karl-Theodor_Sturm/papers/paper41.pdf) it was shown that if $X$ is a complete CAT (0) space, then it has a $W_2$ barycentric map and in [Navas, Section 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5188.pdf) it was shown that if $X$ is a Busemann NPC space, then it has a $W_1$ barycentric map.

**"Submultiplicativity" of the barycentric map**

Let $X$ be a metric space with a $W_p$ barycentric map $\rm bar : \mathcal{P} (X) \rightarrow X$ and $\Gamma$ be a countable group acting on $X$ by isometries.  Will say that $\rm bar$ is submultiplicative with respect to the action of $\Gamma$ if for every $\mu \in \mathcal{P} (\Gamma)$ and every $\nu_1,  \nu_2 \in \mathcal{P} (X)$ it holds that
$$d (\rm bar (\mu * \nu_1),  \rm bar (\mu * \nu_2)) \leq d (\rm bar (\mu * \delta_{\rm bar (\nu_1)}),  \rm bar( \mu * \delta_{\rm bar (\nu_2)})).$$
(Remark: the term "submultiplicative" above is my ad-hoc terminology and suggestions for better terminology are welcomed)

This definition is motivated by the example in which $X$ is a normed space with the barycentric map described above and $\Gamma$ acts on $X$ by affine isometries.  In that example the above inequality is actually an equality since for every $\mu \in  \mathcal{P} (\Gamma)$ and every $\nu \in \mathcal{P} (X)$ it holds that
$$\rm bar (\mu * \nu) = \rm bar (\mu * \delta_{\rm bar (\nu)}).$$

My questions:

1. What are other interesting examples of metric spaces with $W_p$ barycentric maps that are submultiplicative with respect to every "natural" isometric group action? (the term "natural" here is motivated by the above example where is was "natural" to consider affine isometric actions).
2. Are there geometric conditions on $X$ (and on the group action) that imply the existence of a submultiplicative $W_p$ barycentric map?

Comment: The fact that the Cartan barycenter is nonexpanding in $W_2$ is due to Sturm 2002 ("Probability measures on metric spaces of nonpositive curvature"), not Austin.

Comment: In the normed space case you only get equality if your barycenter map is specifically the linear one $\mathrm{bar}(\mu) = \int_X x d\mu(x)$.

Comment: Did you try trees? If it works, what about a product of trees?